# Alphanumeric string sorting with prifix and suffix

Tags: c#

I have a alphanumeric string of array which contains some characters at end of string also. The problem is i'm able to sort only till before the last character. 
Here is the my array

```
string[] ar = new string[] { "DV00154A", "DV00144A", "DV00111B", "DV00100A", "DV00199B", "DV00001A" };
```

i have tried some method but the sorted array skipping the sorting of last character. here is one of the approach which i have tried.

```
public static string ArraySort(string input)
{
  return Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(10,'0'));
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string[] ar = new string[] { "DV00154A", "DV00144A", "DV00111B", "DV00100A", 
  "DV00199B", "DV00001A" };
  var result = ar.OrderBy(x => ArraySort(x));
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",result.ToArray()));
 }
```

which returning the below output

```
DV00001A,DV00100A,DV00111B,DV00144A,DV00154A,DV00199B
```

but the output i need should be like this

```
DV00001A,DV00100A,DV00144A,DV00154A,DV00111B,DV00199B
```

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't help you

Comment: I have already tried these solutions. the problem is it's not considering the last character while sorting. Here is the rextester link where i tried this. plz let me know if i'm doing any mistake in implemetation. 
https://rextester.com/AZCQW42849

Comment: Did you look at all of the answers

Comment: yes i already tried nearly all.

Comment: I reopened the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution:

```
public static string ArraySort(string input)
{
    return $"{input.Substring(0, 2)}{input.Substring(7, 1)}{input.Substring(2, 5)}";
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] ar = new string[] { "DV00154A", "DV00144A", "DV00111B", "DV00100A", "DV00199B", "DV00001A" };
    Array.Sort(ar, (a, b) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(ArraySort(a), ArraySort(b)));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ar));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The `ArraySort` method rearranges the values in a sortable format: `DV00154A` -> `DVA00154`. That values are used the by the `Array.Sort` comparer method.

The only disadvantage that the `ar` array is sorted in-place...

**Edit:**

I found an even better solution: just take my `ArraySort` method with your `Main` method. Should work just fine. :) And it will not affect your `ar` array.

**Edit 2:**

Just fixed a little bug in my `ArraySort` method. (Sorry.)

**Edit 3:**

If you can ignore the `DV`-prefix, you could change the `ArraySort` method to this:

```
public static string ArraySort(string input)
{
    return $"{input.Substring(7, 1)}{input.Substring(2, 5)}";
}
```

The logic is less complex and the resulting values are shorter. It should have a (marginal) better performance.

Comment: Thanks @Bart for providing the solution.